# ¿Cómo comparo el primer caracter de una linea de texto enviada por serial desde arduino a raspberry pi con python?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serialport

Estoy enviando cadenas de texto desde un arduino Uno a una raspberry pi mediante comunicación serial por medio de USB. Entiendo arduino sin problemas pero python y linux es algo relativamente nuevo para mi. Hasta ahora puedo recibir la cadena sin problemas, la idea es mandar querys de MySQL dependiendo de las entradas que reciba mi arduino. El problema es que si mando una cadena que no es una query, mi código se atora.
Se me ocurrió hacer una comparación del caracter inicial de mi cadena de texto para diferenciar entre una linea de texto normal y una query, por ejemplo:

Si la raspberry recibe una cadena como la siguiente simplemente debe desplegarla en pantalla:

```
"Esta es una cadena de texto normal"
```

Si la raspberry recibe una cadena como la siguiente:

```
"&INSERT INTO datos (...)"
```

entonces debería tomarla como una query y escribir en mi base de datos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="admin",password="xxxxxxx",database="conexionRemota")
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    while True:
        #ser.write(b"Hello from Raspberry Pi!\n")

        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        if (line[0]=='&'):
                print(line[1:])
                time.sleep(1)
        #sql="INSERT INTO datos (temperatura,humedad) VALUES (1,2)
                sql = line
                mycursor.execute(sql)
                mydb.commit()
                print(mycursor.rowcount,"record show")
        else:
                print(line)
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando leí que el problema es que mi cadena "line" no existe al correr el programa, quería saber si hay algo así como el "Serial.available()" de arduino, o que otra cosa podría hacer para que funcione. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo que depures y pongas un breakpoint en el codigo de esa manera podrás ver las variables que valores almacena. De todas formas podrías hacer un "print(line)" antes del  "if (line[0]=='&'):", de esta forma veras que tiene almacenado y de que forma

Comment: el texto me llega bien, lo que pasa es que cuando inicio el programa, no le he enviado algo todavía, y como no hay nada en el buffer entonces "line" no se ha creado, por eso me sale el error de que está fuera de índice, porque no lo encuentra. Pero no se como hacer para que espere a que llegue algo antes de hacer el chequeo del if

Comment: Podrías preguntar primero si `line` está vacía: `if line and line[0] == '&'`

Comment: eso lo solucionó! gracias :). Soy nuevo, no se como dar like votar como respuesta, o si tengo que hacer algo. Saludos